# Задержка перед отправкой данных по Serial, Arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, serial, передача-данных

возникла проблема. Суть проблемы вот в чем. Есть плата arduino с подключенным к ней модулем bluetooth, и она сама подключена к компьютеру. С телефона посылается байт данных и он должен переслаться в компьютер по Serial порту. Все работает, но с задержкой. По светодиодам на плате видно что с телефона на плату данные по bluetooth пересылаются мгновенно, но отправляются с задержкой (светодиод RX загорается моментально после отправки сообщения с телефона, а светодиод TX с задержкой в 1-1,5 секунды) ну а далее плата отправляет данные на компьютер, где выводятся данные в командную строку. Помогите пожалуйста устранить задержку, я читал что это можно сделать, но как не нашел. Вот мой скетч arduino.

```
int pinPowerModule = 6;

void setup() {
   pinMode(pinPowerModule, OUTPUT);    //питание модуля bluetooth
   digitalWrite(pinPowerModule, HIGH); //питание модуля bluetooth
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   if(Serial.available()){
   String line = Serial.readString();
   Serial.println(line);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*readString()*

Serial.readString() reads characters from the serial buffer into a string. The function terminates **if it times out** (see setTimeout()).

*setTimeout()*

Serial.setTimeout() sets the maximum milliseconds to wait for serial data when using Serial.readBytesUntil(), Serial.readBytes(), Serial.parseInt() or Serial.parseFloat(). **It defaults to 1000 milliseconds**.

Важное выделил жирным. Пользуем ReadByte(s) или меняем таймаут.